# Dynamic Location of SSIS Configuration Files

Tags: sql, ssis

Is there a more dynamic solution for the storage of SSIS configuration files?

From what I have read, the common solution is to use a "standard" address/folder for each set of config files

I.E "C:\Config"

Is there anyway of making this more dynamic? By driving this from a variable or even appending the server name to the front so a shared location "\server\config" could be used?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. It's possible to store a configuration in a Windows environment variable. You could manage and configure these on each environment (e.g., DEV, TEST, PROD). This environment variable could contain a connection string that points to your other configurations (SQL) or can be chosen directly for each XML configuration file as well.

More info on choosing a suitable configuration strategy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671625.aspx

1. You can work with relative paths, e.g., define the path to your configuration file as `.\Configs\MyConfig.dtsConfig`. SSIS will try to access the Config directory from the path where your SSIS package is executed. This can be annoying to deploy, as in debug mode, SSIS executes from the `bin` directory of your project.

Answer (score 1):

not really, when you are using XML configs, you need to tell the package where to read the file from. Its not actually a problem because if you install it with the deploymentManifest, it asks you where the config file is, so you dont have to worry too much.

Also, read my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663343/whats-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-different-package-configuration-in-ssi) post to have an idea about the differences between the configuration types.

Answer (score 1):

BIDS 2008 doesn't work on relative path,may be some kind of bug
If you try to enter the relative path , on clicking next it calculates the whole path.
The best workaround is to open the SSIS xml search for the path you just entered and make it as relative.
For eg.

In BIDS package configuration window you have entered path as:
c:\BIDS\abc.config
Go to Package xml search for above line and replace with :
..\BIDS\abc.config

and save it.
the work is done, now if you reopen the SSIS in the BIDS window and check the package configuration window it will show the relative path.

To see the xml , go to the solution explorer window of BIDS, Right click the package and click on view code.

Hope this will help

Comment: Wonderful annoyance of BIDS 2008.  Thankfully fixed in later versions.  "Yes Microsoft the reason I explicitly typed a relative path is because I am lazy not because I explicitly want a relative path".